# Find the inverse of a piece-wise continuous function

Tags: functions, inverse

I have the following piecewise continuous function:

> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}3x+1,~x\gt 0\\2-x^2,~x\leq 0\end{cases}$$

and I need to find its right inverse.

Thus far I got that

> $$g(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{x-1}{3},~x\gt 1\\ \\ \sqrt{2-x},~x\leq 2\end{cases}$$

but what can I do when I have an intersection?  For example, if $x = 2$, along which branch will it go?

Therefore, I write my inverse function like this:

> $$g(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{x-1}{3},~x\gt 1\\ \\ \sqrt{2-x},~x\leq 1\end{cases}$$

Is this approach and final function valid?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "right inverse"?  That function is not one-to-one so it certainly does not have an inverse (over the entire range at least).

Comment: $f(x)$ looks [like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%28piecewise%28%28%282-x%5E2%2C+x%3C%3D0%29%2C%283x%2B1%2C+x%3E0%29%29%29). It is not injective, so it does not have an inverse function with domain $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Note that only bijective functions are invertible.

Comment: @Prasun I wasn't asking for a 2 sided inverse. I need to find the right inverse. And a function has a right inverse if and only if it's surjective (It does not have to be injective)

Comment: @KeykoYume, what exactly do you mean by "right inverse" ?

Comment: @Prasun If f:X->Y is my function, than g:Y->X is the right inverse of f if f∘g= id, where id is the identity function

Comment: @KeykoYume, that's the exact definition of a "normal inverse" _not_ a "right inverse".

Comment: @KeykoYume, do you mean $\textrm{id}_Y$ ?

Comment: If you have an interception of domains, then maybe it is not invertible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** OPs approach is almost correct. The details below should help to clarify open aspects.

> According to OPs question, we want to find a *[right inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Left_and_right_inverses)* of the function $f$.
>
> Let $u:X\rightarrow Y$ be a function. A function $w:Y\rightarrow X$ is a *right inverse* for $u$, if 
>   \begin{align*}
> u\circ w = \text{id}_Y, \qquad i.e.\qquad u(w(y))=y \quad \forall y \in Y
> \end{align*}
>
> In order to obtain a right inverse the function has to be *surjective*.

Let's have a look at some aspects of the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
3x+1&~x> 0\\
2-x^2&~x\leq 0
\end{cases}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

- *domain and codomain*

We have added the domain $\mathbb{R}$ and codomain $\mathbb{R}$ in order to *fully specify* the function $f$. This can be crucial for determination of a right inverse function, as we will see in a note at the end of the answer.

- *$f$ is not injective*

We see that e.g. $f(0)=2=f(\frac{1}{3})$. In $f((-1,\frac{1}{3}])$ there is *more than one* candidate for a right inverse function $g$.

- *$f$ is not continuous at $x=0$*

Since
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}(3x+1)=1\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}f(x)&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}(2-x^2)=2\\
\\
f(0)&=2-0^2=2\\
\end{align*}
we see that the left-hand limit at $x=0$ is equal to $f(0)=2$ while the right-hand limit at $x=0$ is different. So $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

> Let's now determine a right inverse function $g$. We choose *similarly* to OP a function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> g(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> \dfrac{x-1}{3}&~x> 1\\
> \tag{2}\\
> -\sqrt{2-x}&~x\leq 1
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>
> If $x>1$ we see that $g(x)=\frac{x-1}{3}>0$. Therefore we get
>   \begin{align*}
> f(g(x))=f\left(\frac{x-1}{3}\right)=3\left(\frac{x-1}{3}\right)+1=x
> \end{align*}
>
> If $x\leq 1$ we see that $g(x)=-\sqrt{2-x}\leq 0$. Therefore we get
>   \begin{align*}
> f(g(x))=f\left(-\sqrt{2-x}\right)=2-\left(-\sqrt{2-x}\right)^2=2-(2-x)=x\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> Since $f\circ g=id_\mathbb{R}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ the function $g$ is a right inverse for $f$.

We take in (3) the *negative* square root $-\sqrt{2-x}$. This implies that $g(x)=-\sqrt{2-x}\leq 0$ and we can use the branch $f(x)=2-x^2$.

> In general the right inverse function is *not unique*. Since $f$ is not injective, we can select *another* right inverse function $h$ for $f$.
>
> We define $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> h(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> \dfrac{x-1}{3}&~x> 2\\
> \\
> -\sqrt{2-x}&~x\leq 2
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>
> If $x>2$ we see that $h(x)=\frac{x-1}{3}>0$. Therefore we get
>   \begin{align*}
> f(h(x))=f\left(\frac{x-1}{3}\right)=3\left(\frac{x-1}{3}\right)+1=x
> \end{align*}
>
> If $x\leq 2$ we see that $h(x)=-\sqrt{2-x}\leq 0$. Therefore we get
>   \begin{align*}
> f(g(x))=f\left(-\sqrt{2-x}\right)=2-\left(-\sqrt{2-x}\right)^2=2-(2-x)=x\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> Since $f\circ h=id_\mathbb{R}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ the function $h$ is also a right inverse for $f$.
>
> Since $g(2)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $h(2)=0$ the right inverse functions are not identical.

**Note:** It's relevant to specify  domain and codomain of a function to determine a right inverse function for it. Consider the functions
\begin{align*}
&u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\qquad&v:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0,\infty)\\
&u(x)=x^2&v(x)=x^2
\end{align*}
We see that $u(x)=v(x)=x^2$, but $u$ is *not surjective* as opposed to $v$. Therefore $v$ has a right inverse and $u$ has no right inverse.

Comment: @KeykoYume: Thanks a lot for accepting the answer and granting the bounty. Best regards,

Comment: thank you for answering my question. I have finally managed to understand it.